# What does u,c,s means in mysqli prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

What does u,c, s indicates in below statement ?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.rank,
        c.country,
        s.state_name,
        u.share_to
        FROM users u
        LEFT JOIN country c ON c.id = u.country_id
        LEFT JOIN state s ON s.id = u.state_id");
```

Comment: Table aliases, your query is not complete (only `u` for `users` defined)

Comment: They are aliases of the tables in the query

Comment: But for this query you would get errors if it is exactly same. `Unknown column ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your written query is incompleted.**

where **u** is defined **as a alias of users table**,but there is no other table **c** and **s** in your query.

```
  u.id,
        u.rank,
        c.country,
        s.state_name,
        u.share_to
```

where in `u.rank` is defined a **rank** field is table of user like or other

**AFTER UPDATE YOUR QUESTION**

"c" alias of country and "s" alias of state this is use for indicate a table using short name if you not use alias than you need to define a field using tablename

like **tablename.fieldname**

**tablename.fieldname**  required only when you use more than one table to identify a field name

Answer (score 2):

In this query they as table aliases which can be appended after select from or joining a table name otherwise if two tables contain the same column the query wouldn't know which table you are referring to.

alternatively instead of aliases you can refer to the table names directly for example `select users.id, users.rank` etc..

However since you are using c and s then there is a couple of joins missing from this query.